# What's the best way to distribute a long running task over multiple frames?

Tags: javascript

I've got multiple long running tasks, as in longer than ~10ms, that impact the responsiveness of the browser. The worst ones, such as loading and parsing 3D models from files, are already offloaded to Web Workers so that they won't affect the render loop.

Some tasks, however, aren't easily ported to Workers and therefore have to be distributed over multiple frames in the main thread. Instead of doing a 1 second task in one go, I'd like to split it into ~5ms packages to give the browser the chance to execute other events (mouse move, requestAnimationFrame, ...) in between.

Generator functions, in combination with setTimeout, seem to be the easiest way to do that. I've hacked something together that does the job but I'm wondering if there is a nicer/cleaner way to solve this issue.

The code below computes the mean of 100 million invocations of Math.random().
The first version computes the mean in one go, but stalls the browser for ~1.3 seconds.
The second version abuses generator functions to yield after every 5 million points, thereby giving the browser the chance to execute other events (mouse move) in between. The generator function is repeatedly called through a setTimout loop, until it has processed all 100 million samples.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<script>

    let samples = 100 * 1000 * 1000;

    { // run complete task at once, possibly stalling the browser
        function run(){
            let start = performance.now();

            let sum = 0.0;
            for(let i = 0; i < samples; i++){
                sum = sum + Math.random();
            }

            let mean = sum / samples;

            let duration = performance.now() - start;

            console.log(`single-run: duration: ${duration}`);
            console.log(`single-run: sum: ${sum}`);
            console.log(`single-run: mean: ${mean}`);
        }
        run();
    }


    { // run in smaller packages to keep browser responsive

        // move mouse to check if this callback is executed in between
        document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", () => {
            console.log("mouse moved");
        });

        function * distributedRun(){
            let start = performance.now();

            let packageSize = 5 * 1000 * 1000;
            let sum = 0.0;
            for(let i = 0; i < samples; i++){
                sum = sum + Math.random();

                if((i % packageSize) === 0){
                    yield sum;
                }
            }

            let mean = sum / samples;

            let duration = performance.now() - start;


            console.log(`distributed-run: duration: ${duration}`);
            console.log(`distributed-run: sum: ${sum}`);
            console.log(`distributed-run: mean: ${mean}`);

            yield sum;
        }

        let generatorInstance = distributedRun();
        function loop(){
            let result = generatorInstance.next();
            console.log(`distributed-run intermediate result: ${result.value}`);

            if(!result.done){
                setTimeout(loop, 0);
            }
        }
        loop();
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

ES2018 has async iterators which kind of sound like what I'm looking for but I'm not sure if they're really meant for this kind of problem. Using it like this still stalls the browser:

```
for await (const result of distributedRun()) {
    ...
}
```

(Tried some async's here and there and at the runDistributed() function but tbh, I'm still learning the details of await/async)

Comment: If you would go through async documentation, await blocks the current scope of execution i.e. if you use an async function, it will return a promise and calling async function won't block any thing else. However as far as I understood the question and can think, I think you should use event based trigger, which we will trigger at some interval and listener will execute next chunk of task remaining.

Using "for await" will halt the current scope and hence it seems like blocking browser.

Comment: It's not clear how you want to use async iterators to represent your task and what you tried that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code. If you ajust `chunk` depending on your computation complexity and the amount of lag you can allow, it should work fine.

```js
let samples = 100 * 1000 * 1000;
let chunk = 100000;

async function run() {
    let sum = 0.0;
    for(let i=0; i<samples; i++) {
        sum += Math.random();

        if (i % chunk === 0) {
            console.log("finished chunk")
            // wait for the next tick
            await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 0));
        }
    }

    let mean = sum / samples;
    console.log("finished computation", mean);
}

setTimeout(run, 0);
```

Comment: why `setTimeout(run, 0)`, directly call `run()` can get the same effect

Comment: It's been a while since I've worked with JavaScript, but this has to do with the event loop. Basically (to my knowledge), the script runs through, and then it starts processing stuff like timeouts. So if there is code after `setTimeout(run, 0)` it would run before the first iteration of `run()`.[[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/h1rwo4sk/)] In this case, this doesn't really matter, but I feel like it's better practice.

Comment: Imagine having a ton of other stuff that needs to run before the page becomes responsive, you don't want to delay that just so the first iteration runs early.