# What's the difference between await an async function and directly calling an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, timer

I recently read a book about async and await patterns, there's chapter about deferred await or early init. The book says:

> This allows a structure that starts async processing early but only stops for it when the result is needed.

```js
const wait = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const fn = async () => {
  console.log("starting");
  await wait(100); // I suppose await should pause the execution
  console.log("end");
}

(async () => {
  const fnPromise = fn();
  console.log("after"); // However after is printed brfore end
  await fnPromise;
})();
```

And if I change the code a bit

```js
(async () => {
  await fn(); // looks like the inner await only takes effect when I await an async function
  console.log("after"); // after is printed after end
})();
```

I mean what's the difference between `await` an async function and directly calling it. Is there any best pratice about when to `await` or when not to `await` an async function. Does `await` truly block the execution, especially combined with timers.
Thanks to @asynts's [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51893733/12644421), I'll post it here

```js
let samples = 100 * 1000 * 1000;
let chunk = 100000;

async function run() {
    let sum = 0.0;
    for(let i=0; i<samples; i++) {
        sum += Math.random();

        if (i % chunk === 0) {
            console.log("finished chunk")
            // wait for the next tick
            await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 0));
            // If await truly blocks the execution, rest of the code are all waiting? 
            // If await doesn't block the execution, what's the point to await here
        }
    }

    let mean = sum / samples;
    console.log("finished computation", mean);
}

setTimeout(run, 0);
```

Comment: As far as I can understand, `await` an async function can cause **inner** `await` block the execution, but does tht mean we need to `await` all the async functions all the way up?

Comment: I suggest you, to use a debugger, In order to see the control flow of an async function...

Comment: The key here is that `await` only suspends execution of the containing function, not the code that comes after it.  At the point you hit an await`, that function is suspended and it ***immediately*** returns a promise and the code after the function call receives that returned promise and execution continues.  It's up to the calling code to do something useful with that returned promise.

Comment: @jfriend00 So if you want to make sure the code after outer `await` to be suspended, use an outer `await`. Or if you want to let code flow,  do not use outer `await` (which means ignore the promise the async function returns, though the containing function will still be suspended due to inner `await`)

Comment: Code is going to flow at some level.  Otherwise, you're deadlocked and NO events can happen, not even the ones that will finish the asynchronous operations.  You can use an `await` at the outer level if that's the desire of the caller (the caller wants to wait for completion).  Otherwise, I don't really understand what you're trying to accomplish.  You structure the code according to your programming objective - their is no generic structure that works for all cases.  And, you always should be handling rejected promises at some level with `.catch()` or ` try/catch` around an `await`.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the difference between `await` an async function and directly calling it.

Well, you already observed the difference clearly in your first two snippets.

> Is there any best practice about when to `await` or when not to `await` an async function?

Yes: always do it immediately. Do not let promises sit around un-`await`ed (like your `fnPromise` variable).

Not doing so is not necessarily wrong, but it increases the likelihood of mistakes:

- it makes the order of execution less obvious and the code harder to understand
- it can cause rejections to be missed (not handled) while doing something else (e.g. waiting for something else, or even conditionally breaking from a loop etc.) which may cause your program to crash. See  [Waiting for more than one concurrent await operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46889290/waiting-for-more-than-one-concurrent-await-operation) or [Any difference between await Promise.all() and multiple await?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285129/any-difference-between-await-promise-all-and-multiple-await)